# An array value is changed in negative value even if i am not performing any operation on it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I assigned the `$scope.option` value in tmp variable and perform operation on tmp variable after all the value of `$scope.option` is changed with negative values.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.options=[1,2,3];
  
  var tmp = $scope.options; 
  
  for(var i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
    tmp[i] = tmp[i]*-1;
  }
  
  console.log($scope.options);
  
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = $scope.options;
   
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p id="p1"></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Baklazan - I don't want to change the value of $scope.option....i jst want to store into on another variable and perform negative operation on temporary variable.

Comment: You can use angular.copy. The way you are doing , the tmp variable points to the same reference as $scope.options. So any changes in tmp will reflect in the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copying the values with `var tmp = $scope.options;`, use `angular.copy()`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.options=[1,2,3];
  
  var tmp = angular.copy($scope.options); 
  
  for(var i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
    tmp[i] = tmp[i]*-1;
  }
  
  console.log($scope.options);
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-repeat="option in options">{{ option }}</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you could help him, with removing getElementById too.

Comment: done with this var tmp = angular.copy($scope.options);

Answer (score 2):

use `angular.copy();` function to copy your **object/array** into another temp array

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, when you assign an array to a variable you don't make a copy of it--the variable points to the **same array**. Thus, when you modify an element of the array by accessing an index of `tmp`, you are actually modifying the given element of the original array.

Put another way, `tmp` and `$scope.options` both reference the same array.

If you want `tmp` to get a copy of the array referenced by `$scope.options`, use the `slice()` function:

```
var tmp = $scope.options.slice();
```

Basically, `slice()` clones the original array and returns a reference to the new array. Now you can modify elements in `tmp` without also modifying those in `$scope.options`